# How to assign interval day to seconds value with llblgen?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, timespan, llblgen

In my DB i have a field named "StartTime" with "Interval day to seconds" data type.

LLBLGen converted it to "timeSpan"

I am trying to do a transaction job and i used the following line of code to assign timespan value.

```
request.tableTransferObject.StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, startTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Hour, startTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Minute, startTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Second);
```

But, when i tried to save the entity i am getting the next exception

```
An exception was caught during the execution of an action query: Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: StartTime4. Check InnerException, QueryExecuted and Parameters of this exception to examine the cause of this exception.
```

What should i do to insert a value to DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, i couldn't find any proper way to do this.

Finally, i changed my DB value to Date and when setting and getting, i only get and set the time part. Date part is always default 01.01.2001 but it's not important for me. I can set and get only time parts easily.

And this did the trick i need. Now it's working.